# Use of 'not' with 'currently'

Tags: word-usage

Being a non-native English speaker (and not good at English too), I am bit confused about the use of `not` with `currently`.

For Example: In my `Visual Studio` tool, I got a message -

> This key combination is bound to a command which is not currently
>   available

I haven't seen many instances of this kind where the use of `not` before `currently` rather it is commonly written as

> This key combination is bound to a command which is currently not
>   available

Now, If both of them are correct then why such two different usage?
Do they convey different meanings?

Thanks in advance for any help !

Answer (score 3):

There is very little difference in meaning, if any, between the two.

However, they are both correct. Grammatically there is a difference:

> 1. X is *not* [currently [available]].
> 2. X is *currently* [not [available]].

In 1, *not* modifies *currently available*, whereas in 2, *currently* modifies *not available*.

So in sentence 1, the statement is that (the feature) is not in a state of "being available at the present moment", and it implies that at some point in the future, it might change to "being available at the present moment".

In sentence 2, the statement is that the feature is *at this moment* in the state of "not being available", and it implies that at some point in the future, it might change to "being available".

The second sentence seems a bit more logically constructed, as the property of being "currently available" is quite an abstract concept, whereas the property of being "not available" seems more easily understood.

Also, the second sentence technically emphasizes that the situation is current, and it might change.

I would personally use the second (currently not available) version, but the first version is not wrong, and it is widely understood.